# Ubuntu 8.04 won't start the setup

Tags: installation, 8.04

I am trying to run ubuntu 8.04 iso on a Virutal PC. It comes up with the Ubuntu install screen and when i click the Install Link, it says loading linux kernel, then it just shuts down my virtual pc. I was wondering how I could fix this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing that the machine is shutting off due to a kernel panic or something.

Answer (score 2):

Please try an Ubuntu release that's not over four years old, such as ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Either **10.04 LTS** or **12.04 LTS** should be tried. Any *archeology* is likely *out of scope* for this forum.